# Concat results from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to concat the results from a query as 1 string. How do I do it?
Here is my select query

```
SELECT CAST(mytable.totalamount AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' ' + mytable.curr AS mytotal 
FROM(SELECT SUM(oitem_total_amount) AS totalamount
           ,unit_code_currency AS curr 
      FROM t_ord_item 
      WHERE basket_id=230 
      GROUP BY unit_code_currency
    ) AS mytable
```

Here is my result set

```
4200.000000 CAD
3735.000000 CNY
19.200000 EUR
19.922175 USD
```

So basically I want all 4 results as 1 string so that I can display is as 1 field.
Something like

```
4200.000000 CAD <br/>
3735.000000 CNY <br/>
19.200000 EUR <br/>
19.922175 USD
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This should probably be handled in the UI layer.

Comment: @DaveZych, Actually I need to use this value in an email template. So can't really do it in the code.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c809/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Table(Value NVARCHAR(1000))

INSERT INTO Test_Table VALUES 
('4200.000000 CAD'),
('3735.000000 CNY'),
('19.200000 EUR'),
('19.922175 USD')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT '<br/> ' + Value
              FROM Test_Table            --<-- Use your Select Query and Table here
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).
              value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,6,'') AS List
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c809/1/0)**:

```
|                                List                                        |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 4200.000000 CAD<br/> 3735.000000 CNY<br/> 19.200000 EUR<br/> 19.922175 USD |
```

Comment: I did not know about the "STUFF" keyword.
Thanks @M.Ali!

Comment: Not a problem gald it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use COALESCE.

```
DECLARE @currString varchar(max)

SELECT @currString = COALESCE(@currString + ' < br/>  ', '') + CAST(mytable.totalamount AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' ' + mytable.curr 
FROM(SELECT SUM(oitem_total_amount) AS totalamount,unit_code_currency AS curr FROM #t_ord_item WHERE basket_id=230 GROUP BY unit_code_currency
) AS mytable


SELECT mytable = @currString 
GO
```